# is GAE throttling me?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine HTTP resource that takes 20 seconds to respond.  The resource does a calculation requiring very little bandwidth and no storage access.  Billing is not enabled.  If my desktop application spawns 100 threads to POST 500 times (each thread will on average POST 5 times).  I believe that 500 POSTs use up just a little more than the freebie time for non-billing accounts, which is 6.5 CPU hours per 24 hour period.  I might be about 10 POSTs over the limit because towards the end, about 10 of the 500 will fail even if I allow each request to retry twice.

In any event, the fact that I'm a little over the limit probably does not affect the problem which prompted my question.  My question is: the dashboard measurement "CPU seconds used per second" is about 17.  I would like this to be 100, because after all, I have 100 threads.

I'm not really good with Firebug or other monitoring tools so I have not proven that there is a peak of 100 outstanding requests on the wire-side of the Python standard library web methods, but I do print "hey" to the desktop console when there are 100 outstanding threads.  It says "hey" fairly early so I think the number of CPU seconds per second should be a lot closer to 100 than 17.  Is my problem on the desktop or is GAE throttling me and how can I get 100 CPU seconds per second?  How can I get somebody at Google to help with this question?  I think their "support" link just goes to "community-style" support.

Comment: What are you doing that takes 20 seconds to respond, yet uses very little CPU time or bandwidth?

Comment: It uses very little communication bandwidth.  It does math for 20 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search the groups for [1000ms](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/search?group=google-appengine&q=1000ms&qt_g=Search+this+group).  Your app will not be given as many resources if your user-requests do not return in less than 1000ms.  You might also face additional issues with requests that are taking 20 seconds, I believe if your requests sit in the pending queue it counts against the run-time increasing the likelihood you will get deadline / timeout errors.

You should look into breaking your code up and doing the processing in the [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/),  or submitting more requests with less work per request.